# Python 3.5.1 - Specific string input giving me hell

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I'm new to Python, and this site, so forgive me if this question has an obvious answer that I've somehow missed.

But I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out why I'm having a problem with this one specific string input line I have within a program.

I won't bore you with posting the whole program (trust me, it has a lot of repetitive decision making), but here's what's giving me trouble:

```
 shirtsz = str(input("Please enter desired size ('Y'-Youth, 'A'-Adult, 'X'-Adult XL): "))
```

NOTE: I've also tried it without str(), with the same results, in case anyone was wondering.

When I try to run the program using Python's IDLE, I get a pop-up saying that I have invalid syntax, and it highlights THIS specific line of code.

But here's what's even more confusing; when I run the line of code by itself in the IDLE shell, it works perfectly normal:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> shirtsz = str(input("Please enter desired size ('Y'-Youth, 'A'-Adult, 'X'-Adult XL): "))
Please enter desired size ('Y'-Youth, 'A'-Adult, 'X'-Adult XL): Y
>>> shirtsz
'Y'
```

So I started thinking that maybe it was a problem with IDLE, right? Wrong.
I also got an invalid syntax error when I tried to run the program in MS Visual Studio:

```
File "E:\tshirt.py", line 4
shirtsz = str(input("Please enter desired size ('Y'-Youth, 'A'-Adult,   'X'-Adult XL): "))
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've literally been trying to figure this out for days, any help would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

EDIT: This is the block of code in which the line is written:

```
#Declare variables and input
quantity = int(input("Please enter desired quantity: "))
numcolor = int(input("Please enter the desired number of colors (1 through 5: ")
shirtsz = input("Please enter desired size (\'Y\'-Youth, \'A\'-Adult, \'X\'-Adult XL): ")
secprint = input("Do you want second print on the other side (Y/N)?: ")
```

Comment: What is on line 3?

Comment: Other variables. This line of code is part of a block of declarations. Would it help if I posted more code into the question?

Comment: The location of the error suggests there is a problem in the previous block of code.

Comment: There is no previous block though. That's the first block of code in the program. You sure you don't mean previous line?

Comment: Just post the first 3 lines of your program leading up to the line that's causing the error.

Comment: Done. How about now?

Comment: Here is your problem: `numcolor = int(input("Please enter the desired number of colors (1 through 5: ")` (a parenthesis missing)

Comment: I don't know about code editors highlighting possibilities under Windows, but there is certainly a plugin at least that would show you this error before you even try to run your script.

Comment: Ugh, I knew it was something easy. Thanks.